# Python subprocess.check_output, with pipeline

Tags: python

I'm trying to get output of

```
dmesg | grep -i 'bios'
```

I've tried this:

```
dmsg = subprocess.check_output("dmesg | grep -i 'bios'").decode('utf-8')
```

, but I'm getting an error.

How can I obtain a full `sdtoutput` message?

Comment: What error are you receiving? You typically must give the command and parameters as elements in a list, not as a single string. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: like this it will only work with `shell=True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['dmesg'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-i', 'bios'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p1.stdout.close()
out, err = p2.communicate()

print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe using `Popen` passing the stdout of one one process to the stdin of another but you also parse the output of dmesg with python instead of running two processes:

```
import subprocess
dmsg = subprocess.check_output("dmesg",universal_newlines=True).splitlines()
print([line for line in dmsg  if "bios" in line.lower()])
```

If you were trying to pipe using check_output you would need to use `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess
dmsg = subprocess.check_output("dmesg | grep -i 'bios'",shell=True).decode('utf-8')
```